# How do I point Apache at a separate EC2 instance with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

So...I want to put the Web Server on one EC2 instance and the MySQL database on a separate EC2 instance.  Which I can do, but how would I point the web server over to the other instance that I am using for MySQL?

Comment: what's your security group configuration (relating to the 2 servers you've mentioned)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know Amazon do offer a specialized [MySQL instance](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) instead of standard instances, just gives backups, etc.

I'm not sure whether you mean how do you expose MySQL service as a port, or how to identify the database instance.

You can [expose MYSQL on a machine port as service](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) and access through telnet or SSH (usually SSH). The default is 3306, I believe.

To get the IP of the database instance, create and assign an elastic IP to the DB instance and use that.

Comment: The my.cnf file was what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of EC2 that is spun up has a number of domain names associated with it.

You probably want to use the internal address for communication (saves you money).  It looks something like `domU-12-31-39-00-86-35.compute-1.internal` and is treated like any other hostname.

The issue with using such internal addresses, rather than elastic IP, is that if things reboot, you need to update the internal addresses.  Your mileage may vary, but I was part of a project that ran for months and saw no EC2 reboots (other than what the team rebooted themselves).

See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?concepts-instance-addressing.html for more on addressing (look for "Using Instance IP Addresses" -- Amazon doesn't like deep linking, apparently).

Comment: If the IP is externally viewable, Amazon will charge you for bandwidth for all traffic across that IP.  From here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/ "If you choose to communicate using your Public or Elastic IP address or Elastic Load Balancer inside of the Amazon EC2 network, you’ll pay Regional Data Transfer rates even if the instances are in the same Availability Zone. For data transfer within the same Availability Zone, you can easily avoid this charge (and get better network performance) by using your private IP whenever possible."